# Как проверить инициализирован ли opengl?

Tags: c++, opengl

Как проверить инициализирован ли OpenGL, функцией glutInit(&argc, argv)?

Comment: тут зависит какая версия `opengl`

Comment: glutInit инициализирует glut а не сам `gl API`